# Troubleshoot packet loss over VPN connection to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-vpn

Looking for any assistance with this.  The person in our group who configured this left nearly a year ago and everything has been running fine until now.

Starting at the beginning of this week, we have been experiencing packet loss on our VPN tunnels to Google Cloud.  We have a pair of tunnels between one of our data centers and GCP-US-Central1. I can force the traffic down either of the two tunnels, but they are both having the same problem.

For background, we have dual 10 gig internet circuits with a CIR of 6 gig on both.  Usage on both circuits for both inbound and outbound is under 1 gig (circuits are due to be downsized once their term is up).  The neither of the VPN tunnels are carrying over 1 Meg/s and usually are 1/4 of that, except for rare occasions.

Overnight the packet loss is almost non-existent whereas during the day it is typically between 20% - 25%.

Nothing else internet traffic wise is being affected by this.  6 other tunnels from the ASR that is the endpoint for the GCP tunnel are not having any issues.

I am trying to figure out how to troubleshoot where the problem for this is at.

Any help would be appreciated!